# se suponía que + conditional/tenía que../past subjuntive

Tags: tiempos-verbales

how much do the titled differences affect the meaning? I'd say they all mean, for example, He was supposed to (do/be etc). Do the different forms provide any shade of meaning? Is the subjunctive one only used if you say 'no se suponía...'?

Gracias.

Comment: Can you give example sentences of the structures you want to know about? Both "Tenía que", and the past subjunctive can be used with several meanings.

Comment: What is a titled difference??

Answer (score 1):

Some examples:

- He was supposed to get here with Alan and they should have been here ages ago./Se suponía que iba a llegar con Alan y bueno debería estar acá hace rato./Se suponía que tenía que llegar con Alan y bueno ya debería estar acá hace rato.
- Weren't we supposed to meet in a couple of days?/No se suponía que nos íbamos a ver en unos días más?/No se suponía que teníamos que vernos en unos días más?